# global variable not getting changed upon method call in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, global-variables

i want to get data of text field present in form action in index.html. I am thinking to do with javascript and if there is any other way to get form data in html please mention it.

My index.html is

```
 <head><script type="text/javascript" src="js/storevalue.js"></script></head>
 <body>
 <form action="h.html" method="post">
 <input type="text" name="bran" value="Enter Brand/Molecule" id="searchstring"/>
 <input  type="submit" value="Brand" class="right" id="startsearchbutton" onclick="st_v();>
 </form>
 </body>
```

my storevalue.js is

```
 var b;
 function st_v(){b=document.getElementById('searchstring').value; }

 function valt(){
alert("in val="+window.b);//printing in val=undefined
           }
```

my h.html code is

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/storevalue.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
 function successCB() {valt();}
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found the link here http://www.thomasfrank.se/sessionvars.html ,persistent javascript  variables can be created  by including this script  without using cookie

Answer (score 0):

Once page is refreshed or redirected all javascript data is erased from memory. You can use cookies to make data accessible on different pages
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: when i use cookie is it necessary to set and get the cookie from js present in same page because as new page h.html opens its not recognizing cookie i set

Comment: No it's not necessary, cookies are visible to all pages on the same domain.

Answer (score 0):

Your sending the User to another page when it clicks the submit button, so everything is discarded when you change the page.

Do you need/want to change the page?

If not you could replace the submit button with

you can use some AJAX library to submit your search and when the results return inject them into the current page (since you seem a newbie I would advise you to use element.innerHTML = htmlCode)

If you change the page you might want to have some server side scripts like PHP to do the search.
you will have to process the url h.html?bran=XXX and use it to generate a new html page.

Answer (score 0):

storevalue.js is just a "library", it won't actually store the value itself. There is one "b" var in index.html, and another in h.html.

Usually when submitting a form using post, its fields are read and handled on the server side. You'd be calling h.php or something like that.

Comment: i need to use only html that is way i am doing it with javascript

Comment: Then an alternative to use a cookie would be to use the GET method instead of POST, and then parsing the querystring in h.html. This would be quite quirky but since you need to use only html..